# WPF UserControl Binding to Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a listBox on my UI, and a backing collection in my viewmodel. 
I have been trying to databind/datatemplate it so that if a new item is added in the collection, a new user control is added to the UI. However, I cannot get this to work FULLY.
To clarify, I can get the right number of controls to appear on the UI for the number of items in the collection, but cannot then bind the properties of the user control to the item in the collection.
This is only me trying to figure it out initially to then make this vastly more complex later on, perhaps good that I have this issue now..

DataBinding WPF Code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SubSystemList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubSystems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:SubSystem}">
            <controls:SubSystem DeviceCount="{Binding Path=DeviceCount}" SystemName="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Properties from the usercontrol that i am trying to render into:

```
public string SystemName
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(SubSystenNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SubSystenNameProperty, value); }
}
public int DeviceCount
{
    get { return (int) GetValue(DeviceCountProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DeviceCountProperty, value); }
}
```

I am reluctant to post much more code (straight away..) as it would only become more difficult to follow.
The Debug WriteLine's in the setters do not fire at all (breakpoints dont get hit). Which makes me think its a path/binding issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
src:SubSystem code: (removed additional properties for clarity)

```
public class SubSystem
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int DeviceCount
    {
        get { return _deviceCount; }
        set { _deviceCount = value; } 
    }
}
```

DependencyProperties on usercontrols:subsystem

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DeviceCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(DeviceCount), typeof(int), typeof(SubSystem));

public static readonly DependencyProperty SubSystenNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(SystemName), typeof(string), typeof(SubSystem));
```

**Another Edit**

Further head scratching revealed this in the output logs:

```
em.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SystemName' property not found on 'object' ''SubSystem' (HashCode=32985660)'. BindingExpression:Path=SystemName; DataItem='SubSystem' (HashCode=32985660); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Makes me think theres something happening in the user control code behind/bindings that it doesnt like, amusing thing is, after i was getting confused, i changed the name of the usercontrol to subsystemcontrol, and made sure all the binding names in the uc were correct.  so not sure why its doing this entirely.. further digging on going.

Comment: But, are DeviceCount and SystemName DependencyProperty? If you want to bind them to your UI, you should define them as Dependecy Properties. See msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: controls:SubSystem should allow you to modify SystemName and DeviceCount. Then they should be modified from UI. Without modifying the values you wont have any hit in the setter. Are you modifying and checking?

Comment: @cicciorocca The properties are definitely DependencyProperties, that was my first head scratcher, i just didnt include that code for brevity.

Comment: Where do you set or get the DependecyProperty?

Comment: @CarbineCoder The Values cant be modified from the UI, its display only, its retrieving the properties on the background viewmodel collection. Binding is one way

Comment: @cicciorocca If they weren't dependency properties, OP would get a XamlParseException when the XAML parser encounters the Binding.

Comment: @Clemens But i think that in the setter and in the getter he should set and get the value of the dependency property.

Comment: @cicciorocca I will add the Dependency property into the code above, but its in the user control properties. To clarify, the Collection that the user control is populated from is another collection, of another object, hence the different names (i.e. SystemName is the UserControl Property, Name is the property in the object held in the collection)

Comment: @cicciorocca The CLR wrapper of a dependency property isn't even called when the property is set in XAML. The XAML parser directly generates GetValue/SetValue calls. Still, it seems the property declaration OP is showing belong to the UserControl. That's definitely wrong.

Comment: If the binding is one way...how do you expect to hit the setter from the view?

Comment: Binding one way from The backing collection in the viewmodel, the setters above are in the user control (different to the viewmodel object etc)

Comment: @Clemens There is always a lot learn, i didn't know that "The XAML parser directly generates GetValue/SetValue calls". However i think that the OP is showing few details for let us understand where is the problem.

Comment: If the properties you are trying to bind to are in the usercontrol and not the viewmodel bound to the usercontrols datacontext then you need to specify a relativesource something similar to this: `{Binding DeviceCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}`

Comment: @cicciorocca That's true. The declaration of the CLR wrapper (if it is one) is broken.

Comment: This is complex because i dont think im explaining it well.. I am trying to bind properties from the backing collection in the viewmodel, and bind them to the user control properties. I tried the Ancestor modification, didnt work, kept coming up with the default values set on the DependencyProperties

Comment: It would be best if you would show us src:SubSystem object, controls:SubSystem dependency property declarations and SubSystems observable collection. Moreover you can use visual studio [live property explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) to see what is passed to dependency properties and what are the datacontexts.

Comment: @PonasJustas Additional code has been uploaded of src:subsystem obj and controls DP's. Thanks for the tip on live prop explorer.. not seen that before!

Comment: @ChrisWatts Your dependency properties do not have `SetValue` and `GetValue` calls. Try this: `public string SystemName { get { return GetValue(SubSystenNameProperty) as string; } set { SetValue(SubSystenNameProperty, value); } }` and do the other one the same. These properties have to be declared in usercontrols:subsystem object. By the way! there is a typo in your SubSystenNameProperty. It has to be SystemNameProperty

Comment: sorry, I didnt update those parts.. let me do it, Following Clemens' Answer below i changed the get/set to what you have just suggested. Sadly though, while this may cause an issue with something else not presently shown, it doesnt fix the binding problem :(

Comment: Have you fixed dependency property name issue ? Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.100).aspx#checklist) it describes the naming convention for dependency properties.

Comment: @ChrisWatts Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged into SubSystem class? If you didn.t, i think you should.

Comment: @ChrisWatts Have you updated dependencyproperty name ? specifically this one: `SubSystenNameProperty` (code samples still show old name)? Because it has to be `SystemNameProperty`

Comment: I think that the problem is that you have set the binding on SystemName property and not on the Name property. The class Subsystem hasn't a Property called SystemName.

Comment: @cicciorocca I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged, but made no difference.. I think the usercontrol is trying to access data properties on the SubSystem object. The errors say, quite rightly, that the property doesnt exist on the subsystem object (which is the viewmodel). Looks like a datacontext/binding path issue..

Comment: @PonasJustas I updated those properties this morning with no luck, I changed the DeviceCount property to SystemDeviceCount too, and seems like theres a datacontext issue going on as the user control cannot find its own properties... If i set its datacontext to "this", then the properties dont get set from the datatemplate in the ui. Must admit im struggling to figure out whats going on here!

Answer (score 0):

You *seem* to have your dependency property declaration wrong.

As example, the full declaration of a `string SystemName` dependency property would look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SystemNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SystemName", typeof(string), typeof(SubSystem));

public string SystemName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SystemNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SystemNameProperty, value); }
}
```

Note that there shouldn't be anything else then GetValue/SetValue in the property wrapper. If you need to get notified about property value changes, you can register a `PropertyChangedCallback` via property metadata with another overload of the `Register` method.

Comment: I think this was one problem.. but it hasnt fixed the binding issue, I still cant get the values in to the user controls. Thanks for this though, I didnt realise it needed the different getter/setters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should:

- Implement InotifyPropertyChanged interface in your SubSystem class.
- SetValue and GetValue of the DependencyProperties SystemName and DeviceCount

  public class SubSystem:INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  ```
  [XmlAttribute("Name")]
  [DataMember]
  public string Name
  {
      get { return _name; }
      set { 
          _name = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Name");
          }
  }

  [DataMember]
  public int DeviceCount
  {
      get { return _deviceCount; }
      set { 
          _deviceCount = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged("DeviceCount");
          } 
  } 



  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged just now on SubSystem, put the relevant calls in, but no luck, still doesnt bind, its like the user control isnt getting the values from the data binding on the UI. its frustrating as its putting the right number of controls on the UI.. just no data.

Answer (score 0):

In your `SubSystem` class `Name` property should be replaced by `SystemName`

```
[XmlAttribute("SystemName")]
[DataMember]
public string SystemName
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```